# Only show results from datatable where link exists in other datatable

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I'm using `VB.Net` and `Visual Studio 2005`. I have two datatables - **dtSales** and **dtProducts**. They both have a field called **ProductRef**. I want a new datatable that has the rows from **dtSales** where the **ProductRef** is present in **dtProducts**. Note that I don't want to merge the datatables, I only want the columns that are in **dtSales**.

Now, I could build a string of all all the **ProductRef** and then do something like

```
dtSales.RowFilter = stProductRefs
```

but that seems a very slow way of doing it. Is there a better way?

EDIT: I cannot join these tables in the backend SQL database.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, work with your SQL command and use a [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: Fair comment. But in this case, the datables come from two different sources, and I can't join them in SQL. Which I should have mentioned in my original post.

Comment: I see, but to offer an alternative we need more info on these sources. What are they? Can be used as Linked Servers?